# Outlook Javascript API - window.open not working from Outlook 2016 Desktop/Windows

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js, outlook-api

I have an Office Add-In written in the new JavaScript API, inside of it, I have a JS function which after some logic opens a web app in a new window using `window.open(url, '_blank')`

It works when called from the add-in pane in Outlook Web in both, `localhost` hosted add-in, as well as after deployment on heroku.

However when called from a command (add-in button on ribbon) it works **only** when the add-in is hosted on localhost, after I deploy it on heroku, the add-in works, shows commands in the ribbon, performs the JS logic, but `window.open` does nothing.

Looks like the only way to open a new window is by using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` but even then it works only if the page is on the same origin as the add-in code.

I would think that there are some security restrictions, but why then it worked when hosted on localhost? Is there any way, to open a browser window from a command in Outlook using the new Javascript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with this has been that `window.open` is not consistently reliable across the different platforms, which sort of forces you to use `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync`. As you mentioned, it fusses at you if you try to open a page that's not on your domain. I've found there's a couple of ways around this that might be viable depending on your usage scenario:

1. You can update the `<AppDomains>` section of your manifest to include the site you want to open up the window to. This section acts as a sort of white list.
2. You can point to a page within your domain that's soul purpose is to redirect you somewhere else. I haven't run into restrictions on redirecting the window, just opening it. I use this method along with qstring parameters to control the redirect as needed.

Comment: I have had mixed results with redirecting to another domain (as per your point #2) in OWA IE and OWA Safari. Would you be willing to share some details about your redirect code? Maybe create a new question and answer it with some details? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `window.location.href` will work for you.

```
window.location.href = URL
```