# Change the default browser to open the link in Windows Outlook add-in

Tags: internet-explorer, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-2016

After doing some [researches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470794/force-outlook-add-in-popup-to-open-with-embedded-browser), I know you may suggest me to use Dialog API for showing the popup. However, the problem is still here if the target website to show is not IE friendly. For Windows client, it is obvious that the dialog API is based on IE engine (, which is not developer friendly). Also, is that really strange that the add-in can even override the setting of user PC?

Ultimately, other than Dialog API, are there any ways for me to open the link from Outlook add-in with selected browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.open to open the default browser from Desktop Outlook, however this window will be unable to communicate back to your add-in via messageParent and the like.

Comment: I can't find this expected behavior when i was using window.open on Windows client. It works well among web and Mac.
Since I just need to show an external link in popup, I don't need to communicate back to add-in.

Comment: Could you share your Outlook Desktop build number where you don't see this expected behavior?

Comment: I had this same issue - everything worked locally until I deployed my solution, and window.open didn't work directly from an addin command that executed a JS function. Basically, the same problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414097/outlook-javascript-api-window-open-not-working-from-outlook-2016-desktop-windo?rq=1 - my build # is 16.0.8431.2110, 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

I have attached photo here
[image]

Select Manifesto containing project and then hit on F4 button. you will see properties window. Then change Start Action value from dropdown

Comment: hi @Shyam, thanks for the reply, but I am now working on Outlook Addin and Office.js. This seems not a answer to my question.

Comment: @PCHC, You can do same thing for Outlook Add-in using visual studio. I am also talking about office js and html5

Comment: Any ways to set this in VS Code?